# v-if not reactive for navigation bar

Tags: vue.js, vuex, reactive

I have a nav bar that has this template:

```
<nav v-bind:class="active" v-on:click>
 <v-btn v-on:click.prevent="signOut()" v-if="isLoggedIn">Sign Out</v-btn>
 <router-link v-on:click.native="makeActive('home')" to="/home" v-if="isLoggedIn" class="home">Home</router-link>
 <router-link v-on:click.native="makeActive('sign_up')" to="/sign_up" v-if="isLoggedIn" class="sign_up">Sign Up</router-link>
</nav>
```

As you can see I use the `v-if` directive. And it's checking for logged in status.

`isLoggedIn`

```
    data () {
      return {
        active: 'home',
        isLoggedIn: this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn
      }
    }
```

So, I'm reading from the vuex store in order to get that value. But when the state of the store changes my navbar doesn't reactively update instead I have to refresh the page in order for elements to appear or disappear.

#### VUEX STORE

```
const state = {
  isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("token")
};

const getters = {
  isLoggedIn: state => {
    return state.isLoggedIn;
  }
}

const mutations = {
  [LOGIN] (state) {
    state.pending = true;
  },
  [LOGIN_SUCCESS] (state, response) {
    localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.jwt)
  },
  [LOGOUT](state) {
    localStorage.removeItem("token")
    state.isLoggedIn = false
  }
};
```

Why is this method not making the navbar update reactively

Comment: The problem is you're assigning your component `isLoggedIn` property as part of data(), so it's set on instantiation but isn't reactive. To have it be reactive you need to set it as a computed property. This way it will be bound to changes. You should also look into using mapGetters to easily map store getters to computed properties

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Micael in a comment above, to make a Vuex state property behaving reactively you need to set it as a computed property. Please, check the Vuex documentation [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html) where it is properly explained.

Going back to your example, `isLoggedIn` should be:

```
computed: {
    isLoggedIn() {
      return this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn
    }
  }
```